# How to get google cast-able APP's name and logo on your smart phone?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing an Android APP, I want to list all of google cast-able APPs which installed in my smart phone.

For example, I had installed Spotify, Pandora(support google cast feature) to my phone, is there any API or method to get these cast-able APP name and logo, so that I can list these name and logo to my own APP, then click these cast-able APP to open it to pay music.

Just like Chomecast APP's WHAT'S ON page, how it works? Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to distinguish a cast enabled app from one that is not.

Comment: But Chromecast APP cant list all of the cast-abled APP after I had installed Spotify, Pandora. so I guess it is possible.

Comment: Chromecast app has access to certain data that developers do not have access to.

Comment: @sunnysun when you upload an "app" to the cast publish, you can allow google to list your app